# Creating a list of many ndarrays (different size) in python

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am new to python. Do we have any similar structure like Matlab's `Multidimensional structure arrays` in `Python 2.7` that handles many ndarrays in a list. For instance, I have 15 of these layers (i.e. `layer_X, X=[1,15]`) with `different size but all are 4D`:

```
>>>type(layer_1)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> np.shape(layer_1)
(1, 1, 32, 64)
>>> np.shape(layer_12)
(1, 1, 512, 1024)
```

How do I assign a structure that handles these ndarray with their position X?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a dictionary:

```
layer_dict = {}
for X in range(1,16):
    layer_dict['layer_' + str(X)] = np.ndarray(shape=(1, 1, 32, 64))
```

This allows to store arrays of various sizes (and any other datatypes to be precise), add and remove components. It also allows you to access your arrays efficiently.

To add a layer type:

```
layer_dict['layer_16'] = np.ndarray(shape=(1, 1, 512, 1024))
```

To delete one:

```
del layer_dict['layer_3']
```

Note that the items are not stored in order, but that does not prevent you from efficient in-order processing with approaches similar to one in the initial construction loop. If you want to have an ordered dictionary, you can use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) from the `collections` module.

If there is any particular rule for choosing the size of each layer, update your question and I will edit my answer.

This is an example of sequential usage:

```
for X in range(1,16):
    temp = layer_dict['layer_' + str(X)]
    print type(temp)
```

The type of `temp` is an `ndarray` that you can use as any other `ndarray`.

A more detailed usage example:

```
for X in range(1,16):
    temp = layer_dict['layer_' + str(X)]
    temp[0, 0, 2, 0] = 1
    layer_dict['layer_' + str(X)] = temp
```

Here each layer is fetched into `temp`, modified, and then reassigned to `layer_dict`.

Comment: ['layer_' + str(X)] returns a string which can not be used as a variable to call specific position of that list: `type('layer_'+str(x))
<type 'str'>`

Comment: This part is used only to create a key. You can reassign the dict item to a temporary variable based on that key and process it directly in a loop. Example follows.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a `list`:

```
layers = [layer_1, layer_12]
```

Comment: So how am I gonna be able to assign them in a loop? `for x in range(MIN,MAX): layer_tot.insert(x, np.size('layer_'+repr(x+1)))` convers them back to normal array which I don't want.

Comment: Also, how do I manually insert a new ndarray? `>>> layers[3]=layer_3
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment`